# Session replication not working in glassfish on multi node cluster

Tags: glassfish-3

Session replication not working in glassfish on multi node cluster

1) application  contains distributable tag in web.xml 
2) application when deployed in cluster c1, which contains 2 instances present on same node, session replication works.
3) Same application when deployed in cluster c2, which contains 2 instances present on two CentOS machines, session replication does not works.

Following are content of glassfish-web.xml (if required for reference) :

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <session-config>
        <session-manager persistence-type="replicated">
            <manager-properties>
                <property name="persistenceFrequency" value="web-method" />
                <property name="relaxCacheVersionSemantics" value="true"/>
            </manager-properties>
            <store-properties>
                <property name="persistenceScope" value="session" />
            </store-properties>
        </session-manager>
        <!--<cookie-properties>
        <property name="cookieDomain" value="node2"/>
        <property name="cookieDomain" value="node4"/>
        </cookie-properties> -->
        <cache max-entries="4096" timeout-in-seconds="30" enabled="false">
            <default-helper/>
        </cache>
    </session-config>
    <context-root>/contextNaam</context-root> 
    <class-loader delegate="true"/>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/safe</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>jdbc/safe</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
    <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
            <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
        </property>
    </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Edit : 1) Does not seems to be a UDP communication issue between 2 centos machines.
2) Tried to create tcp-cluster as mentioned in HA-administration-guide also, but still same effect, session not replicated on tcpcluster.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in Shoal and incompatibility with Grizzly. I have fixed it in Payara and the fix is now in Glassfish too.
Current state is that it seems it works (Payara 4.1.1.154).

Comment: I know long time has passed since this post, I am running in the same issue on Glassfish 5.1, I am using tcp instead of multicast and the instances does not seem to share sessions between each other. Do you know if the issues is still there ?

Comment: @Leonardo I don't know, but probably the best solution would be to create an issue with a reproducer to the Glassfish project. Or try Payara, which forked from GlassFish years ago (note: I work for Payara now).

Answer (score 0):

Under CentOS, you might run into trouble with SELinux and firewall rules. I suggest you disable them and try again.

I had a similar issue, though using JBoss, not Glassfish.

E.