# Is the GlassFish project still alive?

Tags: glassfish-4

I wonder if the GlassFish project is dead or still alive? I am realy a fan of glassfish from the early first days. I started projects with GlassFish2 and have lot of customers using GlassFish3.
Since a few months I try to migrate some of my projects to GlassFish4. But I did not really have success. The problem for me is, that I can't find support form the community. It's hard enough to find a forum. To me it looks like Oracle had did a lot to stop any community driven development.
In the mean time I migrated my main project to Wildfly 9. In contrast to Oracle's GlassFish, RedHat's Wildfly is working perfect. There is a vital community, where you can ask questions and discuss open issues.

So I wonder what is the sense of the GlassFish project? Is it just the place where the 'reference' implementation can be hosted. A reference implementation which is (and maybe should not) be productive ready?

What did you think about this project?

Answer (score 2):

GlassFish is absolutely still alive, [there was a new minor release just a few days ago](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/glassfish_4_1_1_has). It is still the reference implementation for Java EE, so you can expect GlassFish to be around for as long as Java EE is.

Oracle's other application server, WebLogic, still doesn't even fully support Java EE 7 - both they and IBM seem to have similar strategies of maintaining stability in their "full-fat" releases while being more "bleeding edge" with GlassFish for Oracle and the Liberty Profile for IBM's WebSphere.

It's also important to take note of the Payara project, which provides support for GlassFish, but also is [actively looking for and fixing bugs in the upstream codebase](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue). Some of the bugs which have been fixed in Payara have [now also been incorporated to the latest GlassFish 4.1.1 release](http://www.payara.fish/glassfish-411-is-here).

Finally, your point about whether or not GlassFish is "production ready" doesn't take into account the amount of GlassFish which is comprised of other projects, like Apache Catalina, Jersey, EclipseLink, Weld and others. These are the same technologies used in JBoss EAP, WebLogic, Tomcat etc.

It's difficult to get a good idea of activity in the GlassFish project, but [it's easy to see how active Payara is](https://github.com/payara/Payara/commits/master).

***Edit:*** *David Delabassee has tweeted that [the first nightly build of GlassFish 5.0 is now available to download](https://twitter.com/delabassee/status/653815200945082368)*

Comment: thanks for your answer. It sounds as if payara is worth a try.

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm an employee of theirs. Whether you go for Payara or GlassFish, you can be sure that there's a lot of activity going on for both, because everything that goes in to Payara gets submitted upstream to GlassFish. The only difference is whether or not you want production support and how quickly you want to get new, supported releases!

Comment: Sorry, but I found the following **blocker** JIRA ticket **"Session replication not working in glassfish on multi node cluster"** which regards version 4.1 (the version 4.1.1 is listed as the current version on the GlassFish site), and which is inactive since 7.12.2015. So if it is alive, its health is perhaps not optimal..

Comment: Looks like that has already been fixed in both Payara Server and GlassFish: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33669515/212224

Answer (score 0):

There do seem to be forums at www.java.net/forums/glassfish-0 and https://community.oracle.com/community/java/java-ee-java-enterprise-edition/java_ee_sdk but not very active as you've probably seen.  There seems to be more information on the mailing list, the archive of which you can see here https://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive

It is hard to find any information about the development plan is, so I think (especially as Oracle would like you to move to Weblogic and pay them lots of money) that its aiming to be a reference implementation.

Having said that, we've been using Glassfish for quite awhile and have been using Glassfish 4 in Production since April this year.  What problems are you having migrating your projects?

Z

Comment: It looks like weld is not willed to deploy my ear with a lot of ejb and jar modules containing CDI beans. This is crazy, because the same application  runs perfectly under Wildfly.

Comment: Does it put any exception/error messages in the Server.log file when this happens?  May not help you, but one issue that we had when we initially started with Glassfish was that some beans had the same name which it didn't like even though they were in separate applications.